# All object properties are being saved, is it possible to only persist the fields that I've mapped?

Tags: php, doctrine, mongodb

I'm using Doctrine 2 ODM (with MongoDB).

My Document model:

```
class Users_Model_User
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $myRuntimeProperty = 'some value';
}
```

My Document mapping in YAML:

```
Users_Model_User:
db: my_db
collection: users
fields:
    id:
        fieldName: id
        id: true
    username:
        fieldName: username
        type: string
    password:
        fieldName: password
        type: string
```

My test code:

```
$user = new Users_Model_User;
$user->username = 'hello';
$user->password = 'world';
$this->dm->persist($user);
$this->dm->flush();

$user = $this->dm->findOne('Users_Model_User', array('username' => 'hello'));

Zend_Debug::dump($user);
```

My result:

```
object(Users_Model_User)#81 (4) {
  ["id"] => string(24) "4c1d5eb68ead0eb332000000"
  ["username"] => string(5) "hello"
  ["password"] => string(5) "world"
  ["myRuntimeProperty"] => string(10) "some value"
}
```

How do I make it so that "myRuntimeProperty" does not get saved with my document? My models are being saved with all properties including things like "_propertyChangedListeners" which is messing everything up when the model gets reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Doctrine, but it looks like one of two things is happening:

1. Doctrine has a pretty serious bug and is ignoring your YML definitions.
2. You're not "hooking up", the YML files.

Looking at [the docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb_odm/1.0/docs/reference/yml-mapping/en#yml-mapping), it seems like you need some extra "magic" here:

```
$driver = new YamlDriver(array('/path/to/files'));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

Could this be your issue?